# update combobox to default value when other event occurres

Tags: angular, angular6

I am having reusable/shared component in my angulalr 6 application as below for dropdown.

```
 <shareddropdown-list-payments [valuesArray]="cashAccountLoaded" [defaultString]="defaultFromString"
          (outputEvent)="fromAccount($event)" tosca-id="new-transfer-step1-select-from"  [showAllAccountButton]="false" #fromAccoutDropDown>
        </shared-dropdown-list-payments >
```

So this works well, now I would like to update this comobobox to it's default value when some other event occurres on the page.

I tried as below

```
document.getElementById('fromAccoutDropDown').selectedIndex=0;
```

but this does not help.

EDIT//

```
@ViewChild(DropdownListPaymentsComponent) accntDropDown: DropdownListPaymentsComponent;


 clearForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.submitted = false;
    form.resetForm();
    if (this.click=='RedSlip' ) {
      this.accntDropDown.defaultString ="i18n.WID_TRA_selectAccountInternal"
      this.accntDropDown.defaultString="11"
    }
    if (this.click=='OrangeSlip') {
      this.accntDropDown.defaultString ="11" } this.ref.detectChanges(); }
```

Comment: What do you mean by some other event? As of now you have one event i.e. outputEvent

Comment: we have section beneath to this where they can select section 1 and section 2 consider tab table, if they selct select 2 tab the above combobox should be set to default value

Comment: section is in your parent component or child (shared component)?

Comment: drop down in question and sections are on same component

Comment: What? I didn't get you, I am assuming  you have dropdown in your shared compoenent and tabs in parent

Comment: my question how to update combobox to its default value when user switches from tab 1 to tab 2

Comment: In laymen's term, where is your tab 1 and tab2 located?

Comment: I have component A where I am using dropdown which are shared and I am using them into my component A as child, beneath to that I have section which is section a and section b, when I am selecting section B the comobobox should be refreshed to its default value "select atleast one"

Comment: Refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

`fromAccoutDropDown` is a template reference variable, so it should'nt be accessed via `document.getElementById`, you should use `@ViewChild` in your component:

```
@ViewChild('fromAccoutDropDown', {static: false}) fromAccoutDropDown: SharedDropdownListPaymentsComponent;
```

now you can access public instance members and method of `SharedDropdownListPaymentsComponent` on `fromAccountDropDown`

Comment: this did not worked, I added above code with detectChanges but not yielded any result the combobox on top remains intact. see my EDIT in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Taking parent as ParentComponent

Access child (sharedDropdownComponent) in your parent :

```
 export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild(shareddropdownComponent) sharedDropdown: shareddropdownComponent;
 }
```

Now, when you select tab 1/2 assign it to click event and bind that click to a method in your parent's ts like

```
<div (click)="resetDropdown()"> 
Tab 1
</div> 

<div (click)="resetDropdown()"> 
Tab 2
</div>
```

IN parent's ts

```
resetDropdown() {
// this.sharedDropdown.your_dropdown_reset_logic  // dropdown reset method declared in child's component.
}
```

Comment: this did not worked, I added above code with detectChanges but not yielded any result the combobox on top remains intact. see my EDIT in my post.

Comment: your logic might be wrong to reset dropdown menu; this will work when implemnted with correct logic, also you need to import your child component in parent's ts.

Comment: I added debugger as well, it goes into conidtion but does not reset it.